# How can I redirect a /:user link to 404 page in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

## Redux App

I am trying to use /:user and if using the match.params.user method to get data from redux and then returning data from redux but when I add a Route which is unknown I get a lot of errors how can I redirect my website to a 404 page when the router path is not matched.

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from "./Main"
import Navb from "./Navbar";
import Notfound from './Notfound';
import { BrowserRouter , Route , Switch , Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
class App extends React.Component {
 
  render() {  
  
    return (
      <BrowserRouter >
       <Navb />  
       <Switch>
       <Route path = "/:user" exact component = {Main} />
       <Route path="/404" component={Notfound} />
       <Redirect from="*" to="/404" />

       </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
 

export default App;

-----------------------------

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
function Main(props) {
  function hello(){
      let id = props.prop.id;
      props.data(id);
  }
    return ( 
        <div className = "row">
                        <div className="col text-center mt-5 w-25 ms-5" key = {props.prop.id}>
                        <Link to={props.prop.path} className="text-danger lead">{props.prop.Name}</Link>
                        <p className="lead text-success mt-5">
                            {props.prop.text}               
                        </p>
                        <button className="btn btn-outline-danger" onClick={hello}>
                          Delete
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    
        </div>
     );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state , ownparams) =>{
 let user = ownparams.match.params.user;
return{
    prop : state.sta.data.find(card => card.Name === user )
    
}
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>{
    return{
        data :(id) => dispatch({ type : "hello" ,id })
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToProps)(Main);

--------------------------

const sta = {
    data : [
        {Name : "Card1" ,path : "/Card1", id : 1 , text : " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis,"},
        {Name : "Card2" ,path : "/Card2", id :2  , text : " The European languages are members of the same family. Their separate existence is a myth. For science, music, sport, etc, Europe uses the same vocabulary. The languages only differ in"},
        {Name : "Card3" ,path : "/Card3", id :3 , text : "The quick, brown fox jumps over a lazy dog. DJs flock by when MTV ax quiz prog. Junk MTV quiz graced by fox whelps. Bawds jog, flick quartz, vex nymphs. Waltz, bad nymph, for quick jigs vex! Fox nymphs grab quick-jived waltz. Brick quiz whangs jumpy veldt fox. Bright vixens"},
    ]
}

function rootReducer(state = {sta} , action) {
    try {
        console.log(action);
        return state;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }

}

export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Route path="*" exact={true} component={NotFound} />
```

Comment: It only works when my path is not equal to "/:user" .

Comment: If your path is not equal to "/:user " then you get see the NotFound component, correct?

Comment: this is the problem when path is not equal to "/:user" it still search for data in main and use the match.params.user as input to get data from redux when it should show a 404 page